# Random() constructor parameter

Tags: java, random, constructor, random-seed

I am trying to understand the Random() constructor. I understand that if I have code like:

```
Random rand = new Random(47);
System.out.println(rand.nextInt(10));
```

Then rand.nextInt(10) will generate a random number between 0 and 9, but what does the 47 being passed to the Random() constructor do? I've found some wiki's about Random as a class, but nothing that laid out how the constructor works for me. Thanks much.

Comment: It's the given [seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) for the random function, as mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Random` constructor parameter is the seed or starting point for the internal pseudo-random number generator. If you construct two `Random` objects with the same seed, they will generate the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers.

To get around this, construct your Random object passing `new Date().getTime()` as the parameter. This will ensure that you get different sequences each time (when the code is executed more than 1 millisecond apart).

Comment: I believe the default constructor uses that logic anyway.

Comment: It may well do - I haven't looked at the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run your program over and over again. You will get the same output every time, until you change 47 to something else, then you get a different result every time you run.

Why random seeds are needed? Computers generate random numbers from complex mathematical operations that make the results appear random.

Here is how Random works roughly:

```
class Random {
    int seed;

    // initial condition of the random number generator
    public Random(int seed) { this.seed = seed; }

    public int nextInt(int range) {
        // some complicated formula to find out the next number
        int nextNumber = ... seed ... ;
        // update state of random number generator
        seed = nextNumber;


        return nextNumber % range;
    }
}
```

See also:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator
- http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question697.htm

Comment: This gives a misleading impression of the random strategy used by `Random`.

Comment: I'm hiding the formula.

Comment: OK. that seems better :-) (+1)

Comment: Worth noting that a constant seed is useful for testing so you can know the "random" numbers you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

The use of seed is to have more control over the random number sequence. Different random instances with the same seed will produce same random sequence. 
Seed can be different every time to generate different sequence